# Trying to collect user info when iOS7 app launches and use that info to populate the main view

Tags: ios, objective-c, input, modal-dialog, ios7.1

I'm relatively new to iOS 7 and Objective-C programming, and I'm working on an app project, and when the app opens, I'd like to prompt the user for their name so I can then use that name to populate a label on the main screen in a single-view application.

It seems like this would be easy to do, but I've been searching various combinations of terms here on Stack Overflow and elsewhere on the web, and I've not been able to find an answer that works in this context, and the Apple docs can be pretty opaque to a novice user.

I've learned how to use UIAlertView to present a dialog with a text entry field using UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput, so I am able to get information from the user.  However, the alert dialog is not modal, so program execution continues in the background.  As a result, by the time I fetch the user info, the view has already been populated with a blank value where I want the name to go.

It's very possible UIAlertView may not be the right way to do this, so I am hoping someone can suggest a good way to do this.  The code I currently have is this:

```
UIAlertView *nameRequest = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello!" message:@"What is your name?" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Let's Go!" otherButtonTitles: nil];
[nameRequest setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
[nameRequest show];
UITextField *name = [nameRequest textFieldAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

The "standard" way to do this would be to use two view controllers. The first one should have a UITextField and a button. User enters their name in to the textfield and presses the button. Then they are taken to the second view controller that displays their name.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you draw another view on your existing view by using addsubview

After the data you want is collected, you can remove the other view from the existing view using removefromsuperview.

Comment: Thanks!  That makes two suggestions for using an alternate view.  I will explore the methods you've mentioned.